# My macbook pro trackpad's right side doesn't go down when pressed

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

When I click the right side of the trackpad it doesn't press down. It's stuck, but the left of the button works perfectly. What's the issue here and how do I fix this?

Comment: There’s probably something stuck below it. Some food, dust, etc. I don’t know of any way to clean it besides opening the thing up. Even that is dangerous, as the trackpad is made up of glass.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound crazy, but I was having the same issues. I could not figure out what the problem was and it was getting really frustrating. One day I lifted the front and noticed that the battery cover was not flush. So I plugged in the power cord and removed the battery, and I was amazed that the battery was swollen, and in turn not letting the trackpad press down. It was bizzare.

After removing the battery, the trackpad worked perfectly. I don't know if that is your case, but I will be ordering a new battery. A quick search in the Apple Tech website, and it seems this is a common issue with the MacBook Pro batteries. Hope this helps.

Comment: Keep in mind that when battery is removed from MBP your CPU will run at half speed...

Comment: As to the bulging - this usually happens when battery had some physical damage like scratch or smth like this. Also MBP batteries are "not meant for replacing by user" - which means that they don't have thick plastic casing all round them. Thus those things may happen.  Dispose of malfunctioned battery with care.

Answer (score 0):

**Is your machine in warranty?** If so, your absolute best option is to book a Genius Bar appointment and pop into an Apple authorised repair centre (such as an Apple Store), where they could possibly adjust the sensitivity of the pad on the spot. That's probably the best route even if it's not in warranty, as there wouldn't usually be a cost for such a repair.

If you're determined to do it yourself, you'd need a set of appropriate tools for your machine which you can usually find with a Google search. Be warned though that it's very easy to make the problem worse if you don't know what you're doing, as it typically involves removing other parts from the machine to gain access.

Answer (score 0):

A good "WD-40" style method to fix this is to hold your Mac and shake it around a little. It's surprising how well it works.